# Можно ли сделать такой клон, который клонирует не только повешенные на элементы обработчики, но и повешенные на элементы плагины?

Tags: jquery

Есть такой код:
https://codepen.io/codepen_user_2020/pen/VwwXWjm

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <button class="some_button">Нажми</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $.fn.some_button_plugin = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            let $this = $(this);
            $this.on('click', function () {
                console.log($this.closest('.wrapper').length);
            });
        });
    }

    let $some_button = $('.some_button');
    $some_button.some_button_plugin();


    let $box = $('.box');
    let $clone = $box.clone(true, true);


    let $parent = $box.parent();

  // Если закомментировать эти строки (очистка wrapper и занесение в него клона), то будет выдаваться 1. То есть, кнопка, на которую повесили плагин, будет существовать в DOM. 
  // Как же сделать это без закомментирования строки? Как сделать такой клон, чтобы выдавалось 1?
    $parent.html('');
    $parent.append($clone);
});
```

В принципе, по комментариям в JS понятно, чего я хочу добиться.

Как я понял, ключевая проблема клонирования элементов, на которые повешены плагины, это то, что в плагинах используется this. Как же это обойти? Переписывать плагины - не вариант.

Comment: что-то совсем непонятно что ты хочешь получить

Comment: конкретно в данном случае можно заменить `$this.closest` на `$(this).closest` и все заработает. В общем случае - никак